# What is the best way to use the es.indices.update_alias() method in elastic 8.x version using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

```
es_client.indices.update_aliases({
                "actions": [
                    {"remove": {"index": index1, "alias": index_alias}},
                    {"add": {"index": index2, "alias": index_alias}}
                ]
            })
```

This is my code in 7.x version working fine but when i upgraded to 8.x version its giving errors like:

**TypeError: Positional arguments can't be used with Elasticsearch API methods. Instead only use keyword arguments.**

How to use keyword arguments in update_aliases().

Answer (score 0):

The "kwargs" valid for `update_aliases()` are described in the [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.12.0/api/indices.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.update_aliases).

Applied to your example:

```py
es_client.indices.update_aliases(
    actions=[
        {"remove": {"index": index1, "alias": index_alias}},
        {"add": {"index": index2, "alias": index_alias}},
    ]
)
```